# Replacement queue now that batch doesn't accept input files?

Tags: job-control

**Background**

I work at a research institute, and have for a long time used the `batch` command to submit job queues to our machines. However, a recent update changed the `batch` command to be POSIX-compliant, the result of which is it doesn't take input files anymore. Thus, I would have to manually enter each command at the `at>` prompt, rather than reusing an old queue input file and making minor changes where needed. This is rather time-consuming, and considering how terribly `batch` handles jobs anyway, is almost a waste of time as opposed to just starting the jobs myself.

**The Problem**

The only replacement queues I have been able to find are either prohibitively expensive, or don't do the job. I am looking for a queue that simply runs the jobs it's given in temporal order; no priority queues or anything like that. What queues are available now that `batch` doesn't function the same way?

Comment: To be fair, I can accomplish something that is similar to the old `batch` method using `at now < queue_list`.

Comment: Have you tried [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) (or pexpect)?

Comment: @John1024 that looks like a neat project, but it's not exactly what a queue accomplishes. A proper job queue starts the next process in line when the amount of resources requested becomes available. More elaborate queues search the waiting list for jobs that best fit the amount of resources available. It's more than just automation. It's resource management.

Comment: I was suggesting that you use `expect` to enter the information that you need at your `batch` prompt.  `batch` would be what handles the queue.  What `expect` provides is a way to automatically enter programmed information at a `batch` prompt.

Comment: I see, now that would work. I completely missed your objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expect` (and `pexpect`) were designed to automate interaction with programs that want "interactive" input.  `expect` allows one to automate starting a program, waiting for its prompt, sending a response, waiting for another prompt, etc.

Here is a simple example of an expect script that starts `batch` and creates a job for it to schedule.  It starts `batch`, waits for a prompt, creates a job, waits for a prompt, sends a control-D (`\004`), waits for `batch` to respond with confirming job creation, such as `job 271 at Sat Oct 25 14:31:00 2014`, and then waits a second for `batch` to complete and exits:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --

spawn batch
expect "at>"
send "echo Hello from batch\r"
expect "at>"
send "\004"
expect "job"
sleep 1
```

`expect` has many advanced features.  You can create procedures and manipulate variables.  For more information, see the [`expect` homepage](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) and the [`expect` FAQ](http://expect.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html).  The [`expect` wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) is also very informative.

I haven't tried it but it might be possible to create an `expect` script that reads from stdin and queues jobs.  Alternatively, one might create a shell/sed/awk/python script to read from stdin on input and write an expect script on output.